# Find and replace using regular expressions in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, find-and-replace

I read the articles on [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) already. My wish is to manipulate quoted strings in Word (I have version 2013).

I need to replace the quote characters with parentheses.

For example:

> "Hello World."

should be replaced by

> (Hello World.)

I tried searching for `"*"` and replacing with `\(*\)`.

But I was not successful trying that.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `"[^"]*"` with `(\1)` ?

Comment: @Darth: Close, but Microsoft doesn't do anything right. :-)

Comment: @Prasanna: Microsoft Word has, at least since `2007`, had a “Use wildcards” option in its “Find” (and Replace) dialog. It supports [a syntax](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HA012303929990&NS=WINWORD) that is halfway between shell (command-line) globbing and real regular expressions (à la `ed`, `grep`, and `vi`). For example, `?` means (any) one character and `*` means any string (and `[xyz]` means `x`, `y`, or `z`) – but {n}, {n,}, and {n,m} work, so some people sloppily refer to these as regular expressions (even though Microsoft doesn’t).

Answer (score 3):

The [Microsoft Word 2007 Help for “Find and Replace”](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HA012303929990&lcid=1033&NS=WINWORD&Version=12&queryid=&respos=1&HelpID=32) says,
“When the **Use wildcards** check box is selected, Word finds only the exact text that you specify.” 
This somewhat cryptic statement means

- searching for alphabetic text is case-sensitive
  (although you can achieve case-insensitivity with a search expression like `[Hh][Ee][Ll][Ll][Oo]`),
- straight quotes (`"`) and curly quotes (`“` and `”`) are not equivalent –
  searching for one will not find either of the others,

… and probably other things.

So, if your document uses straight quotes, search for `"([!"]@)"`. 
(Microsoft Word wildcard search expressions – which are ***not*** regular expressions –
use `[!qx-z]` to mean any character *other* than `q`, `x`, `y`, or `z`,
because `^` is used for other things (comparable to the role of `\` in true regexs),
and they use `@` to mean one or more occurrences of the previous character or expression,
because `*` means any string, and I guess they thought assigning a special meaning to `+`
would be too confusing to users not accustomed to true regular expressions.) 
As in extended regular expressions, parentheses are used to group subexpressions. 
If your document uses curly quotes, search for `“([!“”]@)”`. 
Or, If you have both, search for `[“"]([!“"”]@)["”]`. 
In either case, replace with `(\1)`. 
The `\1` refers to the contents of the first (and only)
parentheses-delimited group in the search expression, which is the text between the quotes. 
Somewhat confusingly, the parentheses here are just literal characters;
so this gives you the result of replacing quotes with parentheses.

Note that, since `@` means ***one*** or more occurrences of the previous character or expression
(i.e., it acts like `+` in regular expressions), these instructions will not find null strings
(i.e., two consecutive quote characters, with nothing between them).

Comment: I stand corrected: [Microsoft ***does*** refer to Word wildcards as regular expressions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-advanced-HA102350661.aspx), at least in Office 2010, in spite of the fact that `*` has its wildcard meaning (any string of characters) rather than its regex meaning, you use `[!qxyz]` for "any character except" instead of `[^qx-z]`, etc.